# Unclear Output From Function of Two Variables in C++

Tags: function, output

I have written a function which takes two doubles and outputs some polynomial expression. This is a prototype for something (much) more complicated that I need to do later on. The code should be fairly straightforward, but I must be doing something wrong, because the output makes no sense. The function returns 0 or -0, no matter what values I pass to the arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double funcTwoVars(double x, double y){
    double result = (1/6)*(1/x - 3*x/4)*y;
    return result;
}

int main(){
    double fxy = funcTwoVars(10,10);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << fxy << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the output is the following:

```
christian@christian-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible:~/code/HYBRIDS$ g++ functionOfTwoVars.cpp -o functionOfTwoVars
christian@christian-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible:~/code/HYBRIDS$ ./functionOfTwoVars 
-0.000000
```

I have no idea why it does not output the correct value. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to find the answer. The problem was that I was using int values in a function that asks for doubles. That was a stupid mistake on my part.